# How to set up WorkflowService authentication?

Tags: authentication, workflow-foundation-4, wcf-security

I just need to secure my WF services. Can't find any resources on this. How to do it?

Already tried:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WorkflowServiceHost host = new WorkflowServiceHost(new Workflow1(), new Uri("http://localhost/Test")))
        {
            host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
            host.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new Test();

            host.Open();
            Console.Write("ready");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
public class Test : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public Test()
    {
        Console.Write("hit");
    }

    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        Console.Write("never hit");
    }
}
```

And a config

```
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <!--<serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="myAssembly.Test, myAssembly" />
      </serviceCredentials>-->
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

- Can't create a fixed name endpoint because they are dynamically created

**UPDATE** - I tried the configuration bellow and worked, but I want a more granular way to set what binding each service use

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little hackish, but works. Overrided WorkflowServiceHost in order to grab unknown contract names and added service endpoints for each one.

```
    const string DEFAULT_WORKFLOW_SERVICE_BINDING_NAME = "WorkflowDefaultBinding";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        MyWorkflowServiceHost host = new MyWorkflowServiceHost(new CountingWorkflow2(), new Uri(hostBaseAddress));
        foreach (var contractName in host.ImplementedContractsNames)
        {
            // now I'm able to choose which binding to use depending on a condition
            var binding = new WSHttpBinding(DEFAULT_WORKFLOW_SERVICE_BINDING_NAME);

            host.AddServiceEndpoint(contractName, binding, string.Empty);
        }
    }
```

And MyWorkflowServiceHost

```
    public class MyWorkflowServiceHost : WorkflowServiceHost
    {
        public MyWorkflowServiceHost(Activity activity, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(activity, baseAddresses)
        {

        }

        private IDictionary<string, System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription> _implementedContracts;
        public IEnumerable<string> ImplementedContractsNames
        {
            get
            {
                foreach (var contract in _implementedContracts)
                    yield return contract.Key;
            }
        }

        protected override System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription CreateDescription(out System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, System.ServiceModel.Description.ContractDescription> implementedContracts)
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceDescription description = base.CreateDescription(out implementedContracts);

            _implementedContracts = implementedContracts;

            return description;
        }
    }
```

Adding a unamed WSHttpBinding and the following section on service model should work too, but for default configuration

```
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Answer (score 2):

We have an episode of Workflow TV that should help.  [Workflow TV - Workflow Services Security](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Workflow-TV/AppFabrictv-Workflow-Services-Security)

Comment: Nice resource, how do I missed that? Hope this question helps someone else that didn't found this link

Comment: The video is very nice, but as you said, it's about architecture, design thinking and not about implementation. (My question title was edited, maybe passing the idea that I wanted to understand the internals, it will be great, but not yet =])

Answer (score 1):

As far as the messaging part this is just WCF so anything you can do with WCF should work here.

That said with workflow you typically need more fine grained control on all but the first request. For example all employees can start en expense report but only the employee who started a specific expense report can add expenses to it and submit it. You can do these kind of security checks using the [WF Security Pack](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/48114).

Comment: I tried WCF configuration on the web.config section of my example, but didn't work.

Comment: The way I do in WCF is create the endpoint on the config file with the same name as the service and set its binding(and security). But I can't do it since it's the user that names the workflow services. I think that all I need is to specify what binding a certain service will use - How to do that?

Comment: If you want the same  settings for all workflow services you can create an unnamed binding. All services will take that as default. And you can also configure the binding/endpoint using the WorkflowServiceHost.

Comment: Yes, I made an unnamed binding and set default protocol mapping to wshttpbinding, as described on the question. I'm trying to configure the binding/endpoint using the WorkflowServiceHost. The only question is: How?